# adding border to an image programatically

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am adding border programatically on mouse hover :

```
Border bor1 = new Border();
bor1.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10);
bor1.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.MediumSlateBlue); 
bor1.Width = backimage1.ActualWidth;
bor1.Height = backimage1.ActualHeight;
bor1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3); 
//bor1.Child = backimage1; 
adbor.Children.Add(bor1);
```

But its giving error on the commented line in the above code.

Error is this:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred but was not
>   handled in user code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place it inside a border control

```
<Border Name="imgBorder" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <Image Name="img"></Image>
```

```
imgBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
```

Hope This Works.